# fail connection matlab database with mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, matlab-compiler

I want to connect matlab with mysql .when I want to connect the properties "Handel" in database instruction be 0 or error is "invalid connection" .
my question what the step must be following to started connect matlab with mysql and if installion  of ODBC or JDBC is necessary for connection .

Comment: Did you follow instructions from [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/mysql-jdbc-windows.html) and [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.html)? To connect with MySQL you need JDBC.

Comment: thank you for answer can you suggest web sit to install JDBC

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you need JDBC to connect. Steps to integrate MySQL with Matlab are:

1. Install JDBC driver from
   [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).
2. Integrate JDBC driver with Matlab's JAVA class path (Step 2 from
   [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/mysql-jdbc-windows.html))

Depending on how you want to use database (command line or Database Explorer) follow further steps from 2.